# Not condition in if statement

Tags: vhdl

say if i have a signal1, and i want to apply a condition on it how do i use the not conditions in VHDL?

```
if(signal1 != "111") then

end if;
```

I dont want to use

````
if(signal1 = "111") then

else

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "not equal" operator in VHDL is `/=`.

In general, if you want to negate an expression, use `not`.

```
if signal1 /= "111" then
   -- ...
end if;

if not (signal1 = "111") then
   -- ...
end if;
```